# Facebook Graph API Object_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I need to send a URL to list of selected friends. I am using following code:

```
// Use FB.ui to send the Request(s)
   FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
   to: sendUIDs,
   action_type:'send',
   title: 'testing',
   message: 'testing send.',
   **object_id: 'YOUR_OBJECT_ID'**
   }, callback);
```

I am not sure what is object_id here. Can any one please explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“I need to send a URL to list of selected friends”_ – that is not what the Requests dialog is for.

Comment: CBroe. Thanks for the reply. Then what do I need to use? I created a multi friend selector. I need to send them a URL.

Comment: Is it even possible. No answers. :(

Comment: Use the Send dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: That does not work. I am getting the friends list using /me/invitable_friends. this returns a token instead of id. so send fails here. If I user /me/friends, it will return on users who are using the app. Is there a way to get complete friends list irrespective of they use or dont the app?

Comment: No, of course there is not. And invitable_friends and requests are for apps in the Games category only. With the Send dialog, the user can start typing the names of their friends that they want to send your link to (and it offers auto-complete, so that is not too much of a hassle).

Comment: I thought so. And yes, I am working on a game category all. I also need to capture the list of ids to whom the URL is sent. I don't think the send dialog has a callback with list of ids to whom it is shared or does it have?

Comment: What would you need those ids for?

Comment: Only those those users are allowed to access the shared URL.

Comment: And how would you want to check/enforce that in your script? Before they become users of your app, you will not get their ids when they access that URL …

Comment: Yes. They have to become users of the app. Once they approve, they will be redirected to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the conversion [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/) there is no way to get full list of users. You can either get invitable_friends who are not using the app or friends who are using the app.

At a point I thought of combining both the list results and use it, but invitable_friends doesn't return the actual id of the user. It sends a temporary token for each user which can be used to send only apprequest.

I hope this will help someone in future.

Thanks for the support @ CBroe.